# ngFor directive doesn't render anything

Tags: angular

I have an angular 12 app in which I am trying to create a table with ngFor. However, everywhere I use ngFor it just doesn't get rendered and there aren't errors. I have attached the routing and app module as well.

```
movies.component.ts 
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-movies',
    templateUrl: './movies.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./movies.component.scss']
})
export class MoviesComponent implements OnInit {
    temp = [
    {title:'Zootopia',director:'Byron Howard, Rich Moore',cast:'Idris Elba, Ginnifer Goodwin, Jason Bateman',releaseDate:'March 4, 2016'},
    {title:'Batman v Superman: Dawn of Justice',director:'Zack Snyder',cast:'Ben Affleck, Henry Cavill, Amy Adams',releaseDate:'March 25, 2016'},
    {title:'Captain American: Civil War',director:'Anthony Russo, Joe Russo',cast:'Scarlett Johansson, Elizabeth Olsen, Chris Evans',releaseDate:'May 6, 2016'},
    {title:'X-Men: Apocalypse',director:'Bryan Singer',cast:'Jennifer Lawrence, Olivia Munn, Oscar Isaac',releaseDate:'May 27, 2016'},
    {title:'Warcraft',director:'Duncan Jones',cast:'Travis Fimmel, Robert Kazinsky, Ben Foster',releaseDate:'June 10, 2016'},
  ]
    constructor() { }

    ngOnInit(): void {
    }

}
```

```
movies.component.html

<div class="container">
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="movie-info">
            The top 10 movies
        </div>
        <table class = "movies">
            <thead>
                <tr class = "header-row">
                    <th class = "title-header">Title</th>
                    <th class = "director-header">Director</th>
                    <th class = "release-header">Release Date</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody> 
                <tr *ngFor="let movie of temp">
                    <td>{{ movie.title }}</td>
                    <td>{{ movie.director}}</td>
                    <td>{{ movie.relaseDate}}</td> 
                </tr>
            </tbody>
               
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
app-routing 
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';

import { MoviesComponent } from './pages/movie/movies.component';

const routes: Routes = [
    {
        path: 'movies',
        component: MoviesComponent
    }
];

@NgModule({
    imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
    exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

```
app.module
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        AppComponent
    ],
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        AppRoutingModule,
    ],
    providers: [],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

I've tried just displaying the list with {{ temp }} and it does display so I'm not sure what's wrong.

Comment: Your code looks fine, only relaseDate spelling is not correct in HTML, but anyways it is working here - https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ebsmzz?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

So this much code is not enough to be answered. I think the issue is somewhere else in your project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Movies component missing in module declarations
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-c7uyxb?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Please check for the releaseDate spelling in the Html file.You have used as movie.relaseDate. Please change this and it will work fine

Comment: it still doesn't work. regardless title and director doesn't show

Comment: Did you check the console?

Comment: no errors in the console, and it does work in the app.component, but not in the individual component, which is shown through routing

Comment: are other functions working fine in the child component? i  tried running the code and its working fine for me.

Comment: I've added my app module and app routing, am I missing some imports

Comment: could you please share your app.component.ts and app.component.html files. also please check if u have included <app-movies></app-movies> in your app.component.html

Comment: I found my issue, I forgot to declare the component in the app.module sorry

Comment: please provide this as an answer or close your question

Answer (score 0):

The thing you might be missing `<router-outlet></router-outlet>`. Make sure you have that right and also add your default route to your routing module. Something like this:

```
const routes: Routes = [
    {
        path: 'movies',
        component: MoviesComponent
    },
    // Add the below default condition.
    {
        path: '',
        redirectTo: 'movies',
        pathMatch: 'full'

    }
];


in your app.component.html add the router-outlet

app.component.html

<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

that might solve your issue.